# org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8080

Tags: spring-boot

I created a Spring Boot controller with this api path GET http://localhost:8080/api/content. I am not able to run this request locally as it is giving me this error - org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused.

I use MAC and running this on Intellij. Please help me out. Thank you.

I turned off my firewall. I am expecting a response to the API

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.